# Shell Camera.exe from VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Using the `Shell` command i'd like to open camera.  However, when i try the below command, i get a pause of 3 seconds or so and the function ends (no error message) whithout opening the Microsoft Camera application.  Why is this and how can i avoid the problem?

```
sub Main
    Shell("C:\Windows\Camera\Camera.exe", vbMaximisedFocus)
end sub
```

Had a look at the msdn page, but i couldn't get the diagnostics.process object to registed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.90).aspx

Using Excel 13, I've tried multiple options for the second argument to no avail.  Help appreciated.

Comment: Try Shell "Camera.exe", vbMaximisedFocus

Comment: Unfortunately that gives error 53 file not found

Comment: You usually don't have to specify the path for a Windows application but try Shell "C:\Windows\Camera\Camera.exe", vbMaximisedFocus

Answer (score 2):

You need to call it. Try this.

```
Sub Main()
    Call Shell("C:\Windows\Camera\Camera.exe", vbMaximisedFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Rodger, but I still have the same problem, it delays slightly and moves on with no error message and no camera

Comment: Have you called other programs successfully? What if you change it to C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe?

Comment: OK, and oddly enough... what if you change vbMaximizedFocus to 3. It is supposed to work either way but notepad doesn't open with the text but does with the 3... o.O

Comment: Unfortunately still the same

Edit, and yes, notepad works absolutely fine, I'm wondering if the problem is more application specific

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked. :(